# select mutiple items and display selected items using<select>

Tags: jquery, angularjs

My Html is like as follows:

```
<select  multiple="multiple" ng-model="index" ng-options="o.cost as (o.attr_value+'-$'+' '+o.cost) group by o.attribute_text for o in options" ng-change="itemchange()" >  
    <option  value="">--Select Options--</option>
    </select>
```

I'm trying to select more than one item from a dropdown box.I need to display the chosen items as selected and
 get all the  values  of the selected ones in  the ng-model. Is it possible to use $index

Can I achieve this through angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

Just use and watch ng-model.
I wrote an example of multiple select, and please check it on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GFgfogJFLBb4rm2FP35Q?p=preview).
Use ctrl or shift to multi-select.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I want to get the multiple selection on the mouse click itself.since the above mentioned method(Ctrl or shift) is not possible in mobile devices